# how to access first column after matrix transposed in R

Tags: r, transpose

I transposed my data and the original variable names are now in the first column with heading `row.names`

I need to access this column for my analysis but I cannot.

Sample of data below:

```
    row.names CountryData YR1990 YR1991 YR1992
   1    3     AFG          1200   1160   1097
   2    4     AGO          320    417    397
   3    5     ALB          2794   2017   2269
   4    6     ARE          2216   1594   2341

 AFTER TRANSPOSED
    row.names AFG AGO ALB ARE
  1 YR1990 1200 320 2794 2216
  2 YR1991 1160 417 2071 1594
  3 YR1992 1097 397 2269 2315
  4 YR1993 1135 267 2685 858

  #Read in data
 >mydata=read.csv('CerialYield.csv',header=TRUE,dec=".",na.strings = c("NA",".."),  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 >mydata=mydata[1:233, 1:26]
 >CerialData=mydata[,7:26]
 >CountryData=mydata[,1]

#Transpose dataframe
>CerialCountryData=t(CerialData)
>colnames(CerialCountryData) <- CerialCountryData[1,]
>CerialCountryData <- CerialCountryData[2:nrow(CerialCountryData), ]

>CerialCountryData=as.data.frame(as.matrix(CerialCountryData))

structure(list(AFG = c(1200L, 1160L, 1097L, 1135L, 1140L, 1219L,  
1203L, 1349L, 1389L, 1286L), AGO = c(320L, 417L, 397L, 267L, 
298L, 402L, 653L, 567L, 701L, 620L), ALB = c(2794L, 2071L, 2269L, 
2685L, 2460L, 2841L, 2450L, 2833L, 2872L, 2798L)), .Names = c("AFG", 
"AGO", "ALB"), row.names = c("YR1990", "YR1991", "YR1992", "YR1993", 
"YR1994", "YR1995", "YR1996", "YR1997", "YR1998", "YR1999"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You need to show your code here and also `dput` your data set so that we can help you.

Comment: @LysandeR I added code and sample of data before and after being transposed. Could you take another look and see if you can help. Thanks

Comment: It is still not clear which data you use. Is it a data.frame, is it a matrix? I suggest you use `dput` to show us the first 10 lines and maybe just 3 columns of your data. Type `dput(df[1:10,1:3])` at whichever data you have the problem with and edit your question with that weird-looking output. dput output starts with the word structure so don't be afraid to paste it in your question.

Comment: Thank you @LysandeR I have done as you asked. I apolagise I am quite new to R and coding in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in your data.frame these are row names and not a separate column. In order to access those names you need the `row.names` function i.e.:

**Data**

```
structure(list(AFG = c(1200L, 1160L, 1097L, 1135L, 1140L, 1219L,  
1203L, 1349L, 1389L, 1286L), AGO = c(320L, 417L, 397L, 267L, 
298L, 402L, 653L, 567L, 701L, 620L), ALB = c(2794L, 2071L, 2269L, 
2685L, 2460L, 2841L, 2450L, 2833L, 2872L, 2798L)), .Names = c("AFG", 
"AGO", "ALB"), row.names = c("YR1990", "YR1991", "YR1992", "YR1993", 
"YR1994", "YR1995", "YR1996", "YR1997", "YR1998", "YR1999"), class = "data.frame")
```

**Solution**

```
> row.names(df)
 [1] "YR1990" "YR1991" "YR1992" "YR1993" "YR1994" "YR1995" "YR1996" "YR1997" "YR1998" "YR1999"
```

You can store that into a variable and then use it as a vector.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
>table_name$row.names
```

or

```
>table_name[,1]
```

Comment: I have tried both of these and seems to be taking the second column as column 1    > sample$row.names
NULL
> sample[,1]
[1] 1200 1160 1097 1135
@Juan de la hoz